# data binding TextBox TextChanged is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, textchanged

I'm have two TextBoxes (**XAML**)

```
<s:SurfaceTextBox Name="CodePostal" TextChanged="CodePostalChanged" />
<s:SurfaceTextBox Name="Commune" Text="{Binding Path=CommuneGeographique}" />
```

And in the (**.cs file**)

```
private MyModelContainer db;
private ObservableCollection<Commune> _CommunesList = new ObservableCollection<Commune>();
private ObservableCollection<Commune> CommunesList 
{ 
    get { return _CommunesList; }
    set { _CommunesList = value; }
}
```

In the **constructor**, I have this :

```
InitializeComponent();
getCommunes("Test");
```

And **getCommunes(string search)**, is a Linq query

```
db = new MyModelContainer();

CommunesList.Clear();
Commune.DataContext = _CommunesList;

var myCommunes = from d in db.Communes
                 where d.CommunePostale.Equals(search)
                 select d;

foreach (Commune c in myCommunes)
{
    CommunesList.Add(c);
}

Commune.DataContext = CommunesList;
```

At this point everything works fine and the Commune TextBox displays what I want.

My problem is that when I try to call the getCommunes() method on a TextChanged

```
private void CodePostalChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
{
    getCommunes("Toto");
}
```

Nothing happens and the TextBox is cleared.

(It should display something else, but its empty even if the CommuneList has an element)

Answer (score 0):

because you don't bind your textbox with good property, CommuneGeographique ??

```
  <s:SurfaceTextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="Commune" Text="{Binding Path=CommuneGeographique}" />
```

Comment: It works the first time when I start the app, the problem is that when I type something in the CodePostal TextBox the Commune TextBox is cleared and not filled with the right data !!

Comment: Hi Wassim, because your bind is not ajusted, you must to bind with path = name of your property in your objet. for example call your function , set result in property (TestProperty) of object, and bind your textbox with TestProperty , for our example

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. CommuneGeographique is a property of the db object. If it was not I shouldn't get it work at least one time

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: Nop, can you help me to do that ?

Comment: Yes Wassim, go to this site http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial, you have example with SongViewModel

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13418/discussion-between-aghilas-yakoub-and-wassim)